# I am facing issue on rest api call - Property read-only

Tags: connexion

I am facing an issue of
HTTP response body: {
detail:"Property is read-only - id"
.....}

on making a patch rest call on test cases.
On researching I came to know about connexion dependency which may be one of the the issue. so I change the value in swagger to read-only: false

I am still facing the same issue. any clue on this?